# Ошибка ActionBarDrawerToogle() in ActionBarDrawerToogle cannot be applied to

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mDateDisplayStart;
    private TextView mDateDisplayEnd;
    private ImageButton mPickDateStart;
    private ImageButton mPickDateEnd;
    private String[] mScreenTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDateDisplayStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateStart);
        mDateDisplayEnd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateEnd);
        mPickDateStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showDateStartPicker);
        mPickDateEnd = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showDateEndPicker);
        final Context context = this;
        mPickDateStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDatePicker dlg = new MyDatePicker(context);
                dlg.setTextView(mDateDisplayStart);
                dlg.show();
            }
        });
        mPickDateEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDatePicker dlg = new MyDatePicker(context);
                dlg.setTextView(mDateDisplayEnd);
                dlg.show();
            }
        });
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mScreenTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.screen_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mScreenTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {
```

Подсвечиваются последние пять строк с данной ошибкой. При компиляции высвечивает следующее:

```
Error:(81, 25) error: no suitable constructor found for ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity,DrawerLayout,int,int,int)
constructor ActionBarDrawerToggle.ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,DrawerLayout,Toolbar,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Toolbar)
constructor ActionBarDrawerToggle.<T>ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,Toolbar,DrawerLayout,T,int,int) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Drawable,DrawerToggle declared in constructor <T>ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,Toolbar,DrawerLayout,T,int,int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this, 
    mDrawerLayout,
    android.R.string.ok,
    android.R.string.ok)
{
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
    {
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: Данный код присутствует, но ошибка все равно подсвечивается(

Comment: ??? Я привёл несколько иной код, не тот, что у вас в вопросе. У вас ошибка в том, что вы использовани не те, не в том порядке или не то количество аргументов в конструкторе ActionBarDrawerToggle

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался